# Which playlists have the most distinct genres. Display the ids of such playlists. [Oracle]

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi i want to get the result of this query. I am trying to get some results with this query but not understanding the complete logic of this query question statement. This query returns me playlist id with genre names and track count group by genre name.

**Here is my sql code:**

```
select pt.playlistid,g.name,count(g.name) as genrecount from playlisttrack pt
join track t on pt.trackid=t.trackid
join genre g on t.genreid=g.genreid
group by pt.playlistid,g.name;
```

**Here is the database schema below:**
[image: Database Schema]

Comment: I don't think you get the results you're looking for. At first as you group by g.name and then count that one you should have a result of 1 anyway (if working at all), so useless information. You'd likely group by play list ids only counting the genre-ids, though as you join tracks in between you need to avoid counting the same genre more than once...

Comment: You might try something like `select playlistid, count (distinct genreid) as cnt from [the join you have] group by playlistid order by cnt desc` and possibly limit the result to the first n interesting results.

Comment: Ok. So you mean i count distinct for genre name?

Comment: Ok. Let me try this.

Comment: I personally would prefer counting integrals instead of strings especially if `distinct`, should be more efficient – assuming the genre name is unique anyway...

Comment: Oh, by the way: If you count ids instead of names you just need to join `playlist`, `playlisttrack` and `track`, skipping `genre`...

Comment: @Aconcagua if i skip genre then how i get playlists with most distinct genre ?

Comment: Then what do you mean by 'most distinct genre' exactly? I interpreted it as playlist with highest number of distinct genres the tracks belong to...

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the count for each playlist so you want to `GROUP BY` the primary key for the playlist (and not also grouping by genres as you want to count the different genres rather than counting how many of each genre there are). Then to find the distinct number of genres, you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT genreid)` to count the different primary keys for genre and since the identifier is included in the `track` table then there is no need to join the `genre` table.

From Oracle 12, to get the greatest values you can use `ORDER BY thing_you_want_the_most_of DESC FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES`.

```sql
SELECT pt.playlistid,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t.genreid) AS genrecount
from   playlisttrack pt
       INNER JOIN track t
       ON (pt.trackid = t.trackid)
GROUP BY pt.playlistid
ORDER BY genrecount DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

or, if you only want the ids:

```sql
SELECT pt.playlistid
from   playlisttrack pt
       INNER JOIN track t
       ON (pt.trackid = t.trackid)
GROUP BY pt.playlistid
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT t.genreid) DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

or, using the analytic function `RANK` rather than the `FETCH` syntax:

```sql
SELECT playlistid
FROM   (
  SELECT pt.playlistid,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT t.genreid) DESC) AS rnk
  from   playlisttrack pt
         INNER JOIN track t
         ON (pt.trackid = t.trackid)
  GROUP BY pt.playlistid
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

Comment: i think 2nd one is what i needed can i do it without this fetch first row with ties? or alternative of this using subquery or join?

Comment: @AffanSheikh Updated with another option.